# How do I broadcast a message over an internet connection using python?

Tags: python, udp, broadcast

I am currently looking for a way to broadcast a message to connected devices using a standard internet connection. I have written some code but I am kind of confused as to where to add a script that sends a message to devices such as laptops, androids, and ios devices. My code is:

```
# Send UDP broadcast packets

MYPORT = 50000

import sys, time
from socket import *

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('', 0))
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)

while 1:
    data = repr(time.time()) + '\n'
    s.sendto(data, ('<broadcast>', MYPORT))
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: I'm confused on what you're confused about. This script broadcasts a message on the network to all devices on port `50000`. So what are you are you needing help with?

Comment: How do I know which port my devices are on?

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're confused about. My first suggestion is you do some research into networking and how IPv4 works and how UDP builds on top of IPv4. But one device can have thousands of ports that they can listen on. So depending on what your end goal is that's the best I can give you. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to send a simple message to devices connected through a wifi connection.

Comment: What software on your various devices are you expecting to receive this message?  Is it something you wrote, or are you expecting there to be some built-in functionality to display a received message?

Comment: I wanted the message to be received automatically by the devices.

Comment: And do what with it?

Comment: This is for a project I am working on. I wanted the devices to automatically receive the messages sent from my linux machine using python without the use of a receiving program

Answer (score 1):

Just a little mistake in your code.
replace `s.sendto(data, ('<broadcast>', MYPORT))`
by `s.sendto(data.encode(), ('<broadcast>', MYPORT))` and it works !

It's because sendto need a bytes-like object and not str

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

So again I'll iterate that I think its best you look into IPv4 and UDP and how they work. But I'll explain a little here and give some code.

UDP has to bind to a port on a device in order to be able to listen for messages.
If my pc has ip of 192.168.0.2 and I have a laptop at 192.168.0.3 and i want to use udp then I would need to do this.
First I would need to decide on a port to use. I'll use 50000.

PC (192.168.0.2)

```
from socket import *

# Create socket that can broadcast
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)

# Bind to '' meaning we will listen for any message from any IP
# Bind to port 50000 so we can get messages sent to that port
s.bind(('', 50000))

# I'll broadcast a message to all devices on the network that are listening on port 50000
# But I could broadcast to any port. My listen port and send port don't have to be the same.
s.sendto(b"test", ('<broadcast>', 50000))
```

Laptop (192.168.0.3)

```
from socket import *

# Create a socket that is bound to port 50000
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('', 50000))

# Wait for a message to come in on port 50000, and print it
print(s.recvfrom(1024))
```